# unable to move last child of my nav bar to the bottom of the navbar

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, navbar

Unable to move my GitHub icon/link to the bottom of the navbar. I'm trying to use the last-child margin-top auto however it won't work for me. is there something wrong in my code, or am I going about it the wrong way? any advice would be great. I'm new to HTML and CSS so if you see anything you would change in general please let me know.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open sans';
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.3rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: red;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

main {
  margin-left: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/****** Navbar ******/

.img-logo {
  width: 15rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <img class="img-logo" src="img/Logo.png" alt="My logo">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
            <span class="link-text">Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
            <span class="link-text">About Me</span>
          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
            <span class="link-text">What I Do</span>
          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-folder-open"></i>
            <span class="link-text">Projects</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-id-card"></i>
            <span class="link-text">Contact</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
            <span class="link-text"></span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by flexing the navbar (parent of both navbar-nav and your image):

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open sans';
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.3rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: red;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

main {
  margin-left: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/****** Navbar ******/

.img-logo {
  width: 15rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  order: 2;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <img class="img-logo" src="img/Logo.png" alt="My logo">

    <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
          <span class="link-text">Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
          <span class="link-text">About Me</span>
        </a>

      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
          <span class="link-text">What I Do</span>
        </a>

      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-folder-open"></i>
          <span class="link-text">Projects</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-id-card"></i>
          <span class="link-text">Contact</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
          <span class="link-text"></span>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `flexbox` for your nav items so it makes sense to just add the `logo` as a list item. For this example, I called it `.logo`. You can then take this new list item and nest the image within. Next, we'll `flex` this new list item and use `flex-basis: 100%;`. Then you can specify `align-items: flex-end;` for it to be at the very bottom of the navbar.

From here, you can specify `margin-left: auto;` for it to be aligned to the right or the opposite for it to be aligned on the left.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open sans';
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.3rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: red;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

main {
  margin-left: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/****** Navbar ******/

.img-logo {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5rem;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <nav>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
            <span class="link-text">Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
            <span class="link-text">About Me</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
            <span class="link-text">What I Do</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-folder-open"></i>
            <span class="link-text">Projects</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-id-card"></i>
            <span class="link-text">Contact</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
            <span class="link-text"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="logo">
          <img class="img-logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/75/000/fff" alt="My logo">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```